# Can JDeps show dependency of one class on another class within the same module/package?

Tags: java, dependencies, uml, jdeps

I am trying to get a UML-style graph of my module. I tried the verbose class option but it still does not show the relationship between one class and another class within the same module.

```
jdeps -verbose:class classes.jar

com.package.module.MyClassOne -> java.lang.Boolean
com.package.module.MyClassOne -> java.lang.String
com.package.module.MyClassTwo -> java.lang.Object
```

What I want to view is:

```
com.package.module.MyClassOne -> com.package.module.MyClassTwo
com.package.module.MyClassOne -> com.package.module.MyClassThree
```

Is this output possible with JDeps?